# Do I need to call HttpURLConnection.disconnect after finish using it

Tags: android

The following code basically works as expected. However, to be paranoid, I was wondering, to avoid resource leakage,

1. Do I need to call `HttpURLConnection.disconnect`, after finish its usage?
2. Do I need to call `InputStream.close`?
3. Do I need to call `InputStreamReader.close`?
4. Do I need to have the following 2 line of code : `httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true)` and `httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(false)`, just after the construction of httpUrlConnection?

The reason I ask so, is most of the examples I saw do not do such cleanup. http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html. I just want to make sure those examples are correct as well.

---

```
public static String getResponseBodyAsString(String request) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        int charRead = 0;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((charRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(buffer, 0, charRead);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    } finally {
        close(bufferedReader);
    }
    return null;
}

private static void close(Reader reader) {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", exp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you need to close the inputstream first and close httpconnection next. As per [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be transparently shared by other instances. Calling the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance but has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.

Next two questions answer depends on purpose of your connection. Read this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoInput%28boolean%29) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think there are mistakes on the above two tutorial links given as they do not call disconnect? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't say it is a mistake. But, disconnect is extreme case (socket close open operations are costly), unless you really want I wouldn't go for it. stream.close() releases most of the network resources and should be enough. Again, if your requirement is ok to create socket everytime, there is nothing wrong in calling disconnect.

Comment: I will keep making frequent request to an almost same server, and memory leakage is my only concern. If I understand the documentation correctly, there isn't need to call disconnect in my case.

Comment: Using Android 4.4, I get an `org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: early EOF` exception when streaming signal data to a Jetty 8.1.11 Servlet-Container and disconnecting the HttpUrlConnection after closing the output stream writer. The exception disappears, when I remove the call to `disconnect` and only close the output stream. **Can someone confirm this behaviour?** On Android 4.2 it works as expected, closing the stream and disconnection the HttpUrlConnection

Comment: According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), you should call `disconnect`, and they don't close the input streams in the example, which suggest that `disconnect` does it for you.

Comment: yeah, but what if you don't close it?  Won't it time out on its own?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the requirement for calling setDoInput() or setDoOutput() is to make sure they are called before anything is written to or read from a stream on the connection. Beyond that, I'm not sure it matters when those methods are called.