# HttpURLConnection.getRequestProperties() throws IllegalStateException: "Already connected"

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

After executing a request I would like to check the request headers, but it doesn't work.

I call `getRequestProperties()` on an instance of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` and I always get an IllegalStateException with the message "Already connected". As if I wanted to set request properties. But I only want to read them.

The responsible code for this behaviour is in the HttpUrlConnection:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.getRequestProperties%28%29

```
public synchronized Map<String, List<String>> getRequestProperties() {
    if (connected)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
    // ...
}
```

Ok so maybe I should only read the request properties after disconnecting. But it turns out, `disconnect()` doesn't set `connected` to `false`. Although it should: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.disconnect%28%29

It also doesn't seem to make a difference if I read the stream to the end or not. Closing the InputStream before or after calling disconnect doesn't make a difference either.

I'm confused. Can you help me?

1. Why doesn't `disconnect()` set connected to false?
2. Why can't I read request properties while the urlConnection is connected?
3. How do you properly read request headers after the request?

The code to reproduce this is a Unit test for Android (I use Robolectric), but I think you can use it in a Java project as well and call it from main() after removing the test annotation:

```
/**
 * Test if HttpUrlConnection works as expected, because in some cases it seems it doesn't
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Test
public void testHttpUrlConnection() throws Exception
{
    final URL url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection( );
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        assertEquals(200, urlConnection.getResponseCode());
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        is = urlConnection.getErrorStream( );
    }
    final String result = copyStreamToString(is); // some html response
    // Streams must be closed before disconnecting (according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11056207/3596676)
    is.close();
    assertTrue((Boolean) getFieldViaRecursiveReflection(urlConnection, "connected"));
    // urlConnection should always be disconnected (according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)
    urlConnection.disconnect();
    assertFalse((Boolean) getFieldViaRecursiveReflection(urlConnection, "connected")); // AssertionError
    // getRequestProperties throws IllegalStateException ("already connected")
    Map<String, List<String>> requestProperties = urlConnection.getRequestProperties();
    // do stuff with the properties
    // return the result
}

private static String copyStreamToString( final InputStream is ) throws IOException
{
    if ( is == null )
    {
        return "";
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
    String result = copyBufferedReaderToString( reader );
    reader.close( );
    return result;
}

private static String copyBufferedReaderToString( final BufferedReader bufferedReader ) throws IOException
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( );
    String line;
    while ( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine( ) ) != null )
    {
        sb.append( line );
    }
    return sb.toString( );
}

private static Object getFieldViaRecursiveReflection(final Object object, final String attribute) throws Exception
{
    return getFieldViaRecursiveReflection(object, object.getClass(), attribute);
}

private static Object getFieldViaRecursiveReflection(final Object object, final Class<?> c, final String attribute) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        final Field field = c.getDeclaredField(attribute);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(object);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException ex)
    {
        /* end of type hierarchy? */
        Class<?> superClass = c.getSuperclass();
        if (superClass == null)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        else
        {
            return getFieldViaRecursiveReflection(object, superClass, attribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As no one posted an answer in the 2 months since I asked the question, but today I had to deal with the problem again and found a solution, I will answer my own question.

I can't answer all the questions in the answer (e.g. "why doesn't `urlConnection.disconnect()` set the `connected` attribute of `urlConnection` to `false`?"), but I found the solution for the main problem, which was that reading the headers of a request didn't work when the urlConnection was connected.

For some reason, which I can't remember, I wanted/needed to check the request headers after the request was done and the response was there. But I looked at the implementation of `getRequestProperties()` in `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` again (see the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.getRequestProperties%28%29)) and noticed that a method called `filterAndAddHeaders` gets called. So it seems that headers not only get read in that method, but set. I'm not sure why this is done in a getter method (the `getRequestProperties()` one), but it makes sense that when the request is already done, you should warn the user when he tries to add request headers - in this case with the `IllegalStateException` that bothered me so much.

To come to the solution:

I just moved the call to `getRequestProperties()` to **before** the request gets sent. And now everything works fine.

P.S.:

Please note that this is not all there is to it. One of my unit tests ran successfully even though I called `getRequestProperties()` after the request. In that case the `urlConnection` internal attribute `connected` was set to false. I haven't figured it all out, but it may have been related to the response status code 304 (not modified). Maybe this helps as a hint if you have to deal with this problem and for some reason can't move the `getRequestProperties()` call to before sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, backenddev says "I just moved the call ... to before the request gets sent", but when is that?

The error message is "already connected" so you may think that you have to get the parameters before the connection is opened, which is impossible (because the object that you need is created by that call).  As he says, you have to get them before the request is sent.

The code below works for me.  In my case, I'm making an https request.  The TIMEOUT value is an integer (in milliseconds) and payload is a String containing the body.  HTTP_FAILURE is the value 401.  My call needed an authorization header, the value of which is not shown.

The getOutputStream() call sends the headers, and once you've done that, you can't change them (which is sensible) but you can't look at them either (which is not so sensible).

I had a very puzzling problem, so I wanted to display all of the parameters.  (Actually, although I called setRequestProperty() three times, my debug only showed the Content-type value.  The other properties are not parameters, apparently.  Go figure!)

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[payload.length()];
        buffer = payload.getBytes();
        bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bout.write(buffer);
        byte[] payloadAsBytes = bout.toByteArray();
        bout.close();

        String contentLength = String.valueOf(payloadAsBytes.length);

        String contentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";

        URL url = new URL(serviceURL);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection)connection;

        // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", contentLength);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);

        // Display the params for debug
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("{} - HTTP headers:", m);
            Map<String, List<String>> props = httpConn.getRequestProperties();
            Set<String> keys = props.keySet();
            for (String key: keys) {
                StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
                for (String value: props.get(key)) {
                    values.append("\"").append(value).append("\" ");
                }
                logger.debug("{} - {}: {}", m, key, values.toString());
            }
            logger.debug("{} - request method {}", m, httpConn.getRequestMethod());
            logger.debug("{} - url {}", m, httpConn.getURL().toString());
        }

        // Send the request
        out = httpConn.getOutputStream();   // send the headers
        out.write(payloadAsBytes);          // send the body
        out.close();

        // check the response
        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HTTP_FAILURE) {
```

Comment: Oh, and I did all that stuff within a try catch block, and closed all the resources that I'd opened in the finally clause.  That guards against resources leaking if the code throws an exception half-way through.