# Should I close HttpURLConnection in android?

Tags: android, webview, httpurlconnection

I override the following function to do cache myself (to bypass networking lookup)

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    // depending on android version, I use the below function
    // public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        data = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(in));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    // do stuff with data but omitted here

    return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, "UTF-8", in);

}
```

I'm not closing the urlConnection because I'm passing the inputstream which is tied to the urlConnection.

Since it's a common idiom that if you `open` something, you should `close` it, I'm worried if I'm ok with the code.

[Do I need to call HttpURLConnection.disconnect after finish using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056088/do-i-need-to-call-httpurlconnection-disconnect-after-finish-using-it) discusses it, but I couldn't get a definitive answer there whether we are allowed to `not close` it.

Comment: How about copying the inputstream of the urlConnection to another stream which will be used to create WebResourceResponse, then you can disconnect the urlConnection?

Answer (score 1):

Once the response body has been read, the HttpURLConnection should be closed by calling disconnect(). Disconnecting releases the resources held by a connection so they may be closed or reused.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

you can read Uses of class follow a pattern from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

**EDIT**: 
            Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056207) for more

Comment: WebResourceResponse constructor requires the inputStream, and inputstream is tied to the connection.

Comment: can i know what you mean by that ?

Comment: in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());  return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, "UTF-8", in);  You see `in` is from `urlConnection` and I'm returning WebResourceResponse which has `in`

Comment: ok, i am not understanding what is the logic in url connection close and return in, are you asking like you are closing your in then why you need to close connection again ?

Comment: can i ask you one thing that you get the inputstream and close the connection, is there any problem ?

Comment: yes, because I'm returning `in` which I got from connection. If I close connection, application would crash when it tries to use `in`.

Comment: i will say to convert the in to another format in WebResourceResponse and modify the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this before returning the response:

```
final HttpURLConnection connection1 = connection;
in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()){
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        if (connection1 != null) {
            connection1.disconnect();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I guess this is what you want. Just make all closable global and close them in onPageFinished.

```
private class WebViewClientExtends extends WebViewClient {

    // For me it is a inputStream
    // You can define your HttpURLConnection here
    FileInputStream fileInputStream; 

    // Your code here

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        // Same I close my inputStream here
        // You can close your HttpURLConnection here
        if(fileInputStream == null) return;
        try {
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

Set our own extended class to the webView then it's done:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientExtends());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my test, there is no need to close InputStream.

See the code below, the log "close" has been printed immediately.

```
                    if (file.exists()) {
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file) {
                        @Override
                        public void close() throws IOException {
                            super.close();
                            Log.d("zzz", "close");
                        }
                    };
                    return new WebResourceResponse("image/png", "UTF-8", in);
```