# Memory Leak with AsyncTask

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

i appear to have a memory leak with the following asyncTask, what possible cause are there?

```
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
public class PostLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String response = "";



            URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + "receiveLocation.php");

            myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            myConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(myConnection.getOutputStream());

            wr.writeBytes(params[0]);
            int responseCode = myConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response += line;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return response = "";
            }
            return response;


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "false";
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if(result.equals("success"))
        {
            myConnection.disconnect();
        }


    }

}
```

this is simply posting some data to my server. What could be causing memory leaks, note this task is called in the background from a broadcast receiver using goAsync

Comment: adding logcat will give more info about issue pleas add it.

Comment: Is this class placed in a separate .java file or is it a nested class?

Comment: @Kelevandos it is an inner class inside my broadcast receiver

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is in your class structure.

A nested class should be declared *static* whenever possible, otherwise it will keep the enclosing class in memory, leading to memory leaks.

Change:

```
public class PostLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

to:

```
public static class PostLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

Here is an exercise:

- Put a field called `boolean test` in your BroadcastReceiver class
- Now in your nested class, try to access this field, e.g. `test == true`

If the nested class is **not static**, you will be able to access the field. This is because the instance of the class keeps the reference to the enclosing class. But if you make `PostLocation` class *static*, the field will not be available.

Comment: i am doing both the answers here but every call to this task increases the ram usage by about 0.1 mb and this call runs every 3 minutes, if i remove the call it doesn't increase

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to close the inputstream first and close httpconnection next. As per [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but
>   the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be
>   transparently shared by other instances. Calling the close() methods
>   on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a
>   request may free network resources associated with this instance but
>   has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the
>   disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent
>   connection is otherwise idle at that time.

[**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056088/do-i-need-to-call-httpurlconnection-disconnect-after-finish-using-it)

Comment: taking the other answer into consideration i cant close the connection like i do above if the class is static, or do i just make the connection and the input stream static?

Comment: try to close before `br.close();` before `return response;` in `doInBackground`

Comment: i am doing both the answers here but every call to this task increases the ram usage by about 0.1 mb and this call runs every 3 minutes, if i remove the call it doesn't increase